# Error VPCResourceNotSpecified

Tags: cloudify

I'm getting an error when trying to deploy an instance in Amazon. I'm using Cloudify 3.2.1.

My blueprint:

```
...
node_templates:

  host:
    type: cloudify.aws.nodes.Instance
    properties:
      image_id: { get_input: image }
      instance_type: { get_input: size_wordpress }
...
```

My inputs:

```
...
size_wordpress: t2.small
...
```

Error:

```
<Code>VPCResourceNotSpecified</Code>
<Message>The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or network interface ID is required to carry out the request.</Message>
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 3):

T2 instance types require a VPC and not EC2 Classic.

You can either use VPC or use a different instance type.

[EC2 instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

[Cloudify VPC spec](http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.3.1/plugins/aws/)

Comment: Please note that 3.2.1 does not support VPC.

Comment: Worked in terraform too... Thanks a lot.